# Save current user Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I created a form through Symfony2 crud generator. I have a user which is actually not related to the current entity and I want it to automatically save the createdby field by the current user as its value.How did you do it? I tried

```
$entity = new Department();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       // var_dump($userId);
        //die();
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $userId = $user->getUsername();
          var_dump($userId);
        die();//check if user not empty in this case, it return username returns current username
        $entity->$user;
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my comments :

```
 $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $userId = $user->getUsername();
              var_dump($userId);
            die(); // This finish the script remove if you want to execute the rest of the script
            $entity->$user; //This does nothing change by the next line
            $entity->user = $user; //user for user object or userId if you want to store the username
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
```

Comment: This does not working.BTW I have a createdby field in that entity

Comment: If you have the createdby field change the line $entity->user = $user; by $entity->createby = $user;

Comment: yeah I already it but it doesnt work.Error tells cannot accesss private property.Changing to public make this work but I think it is not a good idea setting public properties in Symfony entity since it is set private by default.If someone can tell me it is doesnt matter setting public property then I will do it and accept your answer

Comment: You must have getter and setter for that property. Something like public function setCreatedby($user) and public function getCreatedby(). use $entity->setCreatedby($user);